# Does Wu's condition give him the power to see Wesen woge?

Tags: grimm

We know that Wesen have two kinds of woge. One where anyone can perceive it (usually right before the Wesen rips them apart) and one that seems more involuntary, which only Grimms and other Wesen can see. This is what lets Nick see that a suspect is Wesen (and lets them see that he's a Grimm). Some sort of magical mental block prevents ordinary humans from seeing this latter woge, be it in person or on film.

In the fifth season of *Grimm*, Wu gets infected with something after being bitten or scratched by a lycanthrope Blutbad, after which he seems to woge (or something similar) under conditions of high stress, becoming something that looks very much like a Blutbad (with the accompanying strength, claws, and so forth). Monroe says that Wu is "not Wesen" (but doesn't seem to be speaking from any knowledge, in any case).

Does this quasi-Blutbad state give Wu the ability to see Wesen even when they don't intentionally woge?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I say no, because Nick always saw Wessen first, and Wu being in the same place did not know. Nor Monroe (Silas Weir Mitchell ) saw these things first, most of the time, with Nick and Monroe being in the same place with Wessen... So Monroe I know has, but as I said Nick is always the first to know when in the company of Monroe and Wu.... Wu has not ever seen Wessen until they woge....

Comment: Yes, but what about *after* Wu became a "Blutbad" (or whatever he became)?